# variadic template for << operator for simple logger

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, variadic-templates

Can you help me with the following problem ?
I am trying to use the variadic templates and pack expansion to write a logger. The problem is I know that operator<< must accept only two arguments - the second argument then becomes a whole pack, and I do not know how to expand '`const Args& ...rest`' to '`const T& v, const Args& ...rest`'
Can any guru explain how to re-write the variadic expression to achieve this goal ? The end game is to have code like:
`log << "string" << 1 << 1.2`;

being printed together at once.
(Please excuse the cout, it is just for example purposes. Idea is to collect all the arguments in `oss_` and then print them once.).
The compiler current complains, which I understand is the issue with operator<< accepting only two arguments.

```
‘LogHandle& operator<<(LogHandle&, const T&, const Args& ...)’ must take exactly two argument
```

Here is the code:

```
 #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <sstream>

    class LogHandle {
        public:
        template<typename T>
        friend LogHandle& operator<<(LogHandle& l, const T& v)
        {
            l.oss_ << v;
            std::cout << "Value is: " << l.oss_.str().c_str();
            l.oss_.str("");
            l.oss_.clear();
            return l;
        }

        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        friend LogHandle& operator<<(LogHandle& l, const T& v, const Args&... rest)
        {
            l.oss_ << v << " ";
            return l << (rest...);
        }

        std::ostringstream oss_;
    };

    int main(int, char**)
    {  
        LogHandle log;
        log << "String" << 1;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it's not possible to directly detect that you've reached the end of the statement. Perhaps forcing a syntax of `LogHandle() << ... << ...;` would be possible (to allow detection through the destructor), but I imagine would come with edge cases.

Comment: yea, I wanted to avoid construction/destruction on every call, which is why I was going down the pack expansion route.

Comment: `operator<<` must take exactly two arguments, of exactly two types. Trying to make it a variadic template is pointless. What do you mean by "collect all the arguments together"? Collect where?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question - what I mean is that I want to collect all arguments in the oss_ member and print them when no more arguments remain. The variadic operator<<() only expands the argument - the simple operator<<() is the one that prints the oss_ once. See another example here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439779.aspx)

Comment: Create a proxy class. `LogHandle::operator<<` would return a temporary instance of that proxy, which would hold a pointer back to `LogHandle` instance. The proxy would itself implement `operator<<`, which would forward the call to some private `LogHandle` method and then return a reference to itself. At the semicolon, the proxy would be destroyed, and in its destructor, signal to `LogHandle` that the end of statement has been reached.

Comment: Having said that, personally I feel that having `log << a << b;` behave differently than `log << a; log <<  b;` would violate the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Thinking about those in terms of logging and not C++, I can't say I would be too surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible exactly the way you want it, because the arity of operators is fixed—you cannot make them variadic.

However, you can instead use a proxy returned from your `operator <<` to "collect" all the arguments in one place. Something like this:

```
class LogHandle
{
    template<typename T>
    friend LogProxy operator<<(LogHandle& l, const T& v)
    {
        LogProxy p(*this);
        p << v;
        return p;
    }

    void print(const std::ostringstream &oss)
    {
       std::cout << "Value is: " << oss.str();
    }
};

struct LogProxy
{
  LogHandle *handle;
  std::ostringstream oss_;

  LogProxy(LogHandle &l) : handle(&l) {}

  LogProxy(LogProxy &&rhs) : handle(rhs.handle) { rhs.handle = nullptr; }

  template <class T>
  friend LogProxy& operator<< (LogProxy &p, const T &v)
  {
    p.oss_ << v;
    return p;
  }

  ~LogProxy()
  {
    if (handle) handle->print(oss_);
  }
};
```

Comment: there is a problem - LogHandle returns Lvalue of LogProxy and LogProxy's operator<<() is not defined for Lvalue, but for reference.

Comment: if you define the LogProxy::operator<<() to return and accept a simple non-ref value it would work fine probably because of it is movable.